# How could I use regular expression to split Chinese characters at right position?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to split specific Chinese characters in some lines. Actually, it worked, but the position of the split character was wrong. How could I split it at right position?

I split Chinese characters by regular expression in python 3.6

```
str = '我到家'
pattern = '([\u4e00-\u9fa5]?(?:到))'
compiled_pattern = re.compile(pattern)
new_str = re.split(compiled_pattern, str)
print(new_str)
```

The output by my code is

```
['', '我到', '家']
```

But what I want is

```
['我', '到', '家']
```

How could I fix it and spit the character at right position?

Answer (score 1):

Just do like this

```
list(str)
```

I tried it, and output is the same as you want

```
['我', '到', '家']
```

Comment: That is incorrect in a rather specific way. It breaks up the unicode into codepoints and not into grapheme morpheme clusters which is what visually appear as a single character. But is actually comprised of base and composite and modifier codepoints, there can be many code points per GMC. This is the reason that I think unicode strings should not be iterable. There is no good choice for a default iterator so it is better to make the user chose rather than having a bad default.

Comment: thanks a lot, but this isn't a good way for my case. because the real CH characters are obtained form value in dict. Moreover, the split words might contain 2-3 words. Here I posted is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
str = '我到家'
pattern = '(我)(到)(家)'
compiled_pattern = re.compile(pattern)
new_str = list(re.findall(compiled_pattern,str)[0])
print(new_str)
```

Comment: It might a good solution for me in particular case. However, sometimes I have to reserve the split words for further encoding. Therefore, I need a way to do the both things in same time. Thanks for help.

Comment: Additionally , I tried pattern = '([\u4e00-\u9fa5]{,0}?(?:到))', and it worked. Even so, I can't figure it out why it can be.